# Check 2 values in aiml file

Tags: aiml, program-o

How can I check 2 values in condition or with other tags?
I want check if the user's name is equal with Unknown user value but I don't know how can I do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have the user name stored in a global property (predicate) called *user*, using `<set name="user">George</set>` You can check the user's name with an AIML category like this:

```
<category>
  <pattern>WHAT IS MY NAME</pattern>
  <template>
    <condition>
      <li name="user" value="unknown">You haven't told me your name</li>
      <li name="user" value="">You haven't told me your name</li>
      <li>Hello <get name="user"/>!</li>
    </condition>
  </template>
<category>
```

This works as follows:

1. You set up a category that responds to user input "What is my name"
2. The `<li>` elements in the `<condition>` test the *name* property for unknown and blank. In this case the AI replies the user hasn't told us their name.
3. The final `<li>` element is triggered if we have a name, and it replies with 'Hello' followed by the user name.

I haven't tested this with program O but it's standard AIML and should work fine. I have successfully coded similar categories in my own AI.

Comment: Hmm I can't upvote. Something 15 reputation things come up instead. :D Anyway thank you. :) It works. :D